# Android create Spannable which does not wrap

Tags: android, textview, android-appwidget, spannablestring

I have a following issue with laying out text on Android. I'm basically trying to have two lines of text with minimal spacing and each should be styled differently. I've had quite good working solution with two singlelined TextViews one placed below the other, but I've been still getting a little bit cropped text on certain devices..

So I decided to switch to just one TextView an use Spannables instead which should be generally a better solution in all circumstances.

That means I needed to remove the single line property from my TextView -> in order to be able to wrap the line before starting the second Spannable..But there is an issue when is the text displayed at the first line actually longer than it..TextView wraps Automaticaly which is an unwanted behavior. Below you can see several screenshots, which should you better tell what I'm trying to achieve and where I'm now.

The first image shows new layout with spannables and you can see there the wrapped line as well.
The second image is the initial version of the layout woth two textviews layed out verically in a LinearLayout.

There is also a problem it's actually an appwidget, that means I do not have an access to that textview instance directly. I have been thinking about ditching textviews at all and instead use just ImageView and render all manually on canvas..That seems like an overkill to me, so I'm looking for a better solution. Unfortunately I'm kind of out of ideas and knowledge:)

Thank you

[image: this is the new layout with spannables, but there is the unwanted crop]
[image: this is the old layout you can see there were two textviews below each other]

Comment: Got same issues, did you find any solution to this?

Comment: Got the same issue, haven't found a solution yet...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to prevent a multi-word string from wrapping, you can replace the spaces with [non-breaking spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space) ('\u00A0'). TextView treats these as word characters, but renders them as spaces.